# More concise way to cast division of integers to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, casting

I'm trying to divide some integers to get a percentage.  By default I get an integer result, of course, so I cast to decimal.  But I also would like the result to only have two places to the right of the decimal.

```
--select (x - y) / y

select (82 - 56) / 56                                      --0
select (82 - 56) / cast(56 as decimal(9, 2))               --0.4642857142
select cast(82 - 56 as decimal(9,2)) / 56                  --0.464285
select cast((82 - 56) / 56 as decimal(9,2))                --0.00

select cast(cast(82 - 56 as decimal) / 56 as decimal(9,2)) --.46
```

So I end up having to cast both one of the operands and the entire expression in order to get the result I want.  Is there a better way to do this?

Notice I put the equation up top to signify that I am obviously not working with hardcoded numbers (i.e. Suggesting I just put ".0" after the numbers would be less than helpful).  Also, I would normally leave the formatting aspect to reporting software, but this is being copied from time to time into an excel spreadsheet and I would have to hand format it every time.

Comment: @Quassnoi Oops, sql 2008... just added the tag, thanks.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be done in sql, or can you get back the results in Java / C# / PhP? This would be a snap to do in any of those languages, and I actually think you'd save download bandwidth because of the size of decimal

Comment: What about writing a user defined function that does the calculation and rounding as you want it?

Comment: @BrandonMoore after reading the question fully, I updated my comment.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Yeah I noticed :)

Comment: @ThomasMueller That would certainly work.  Was kind of looking for a more versatile answer that wouldn't have to be fitted to this one equation though although I'm thinking there might not be one.

Comment: What about `cast((x - y + 0.0) / y as decimal(9,2))`? I didn't test if it works, but it should. It would still allow you to use non-hardcoded values.

Comment: Yep, I think that would work well... very similar to Quassnoi's answer.  His answer was just ever so sliiiiightly better though because it showed that I don't need the '0' after the decimal :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dividing a `DECIMAL` by an `INTEGER`, `SQL Server` yields a `DECIMAL` with precision defined as p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1), where `sn` and `pn` are the scale and the precision of the 1st and 2nd arguments (the divident and the divisor).

The simplest way would be:

```
SELECT  CAST(1. * (x - y) / y AS DECIMAL(9, 2))
```

`1.` is a `DECIMAL(1, 0)` which, being multiplied by an integer, yields a `DECIMAL(n, 0)`. Being divided by an integer, it would then yield a `DECIMAL(n, 6)` (for the number orders similar to those in your example).

It then needs to be cast to `DECIMAL(9, 2)` to truncate the extra digits.